# Openssl string decryption in Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, openssl, dollar-sign

I have a Perl script which takes a input string. The string contains `$`'s sign in it. The string is encrypted using openssl and decrypted back. `enc` and `dec` are the encrypted and decrypted strings in the below code snippet.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'build:$6$n2cR7cY/$aKv6qQRWjYMIQIyAdTsw6nPtMzEZoqHziqyrL9sn/m29k5mkQjgcwZarA.8lAte6mmDGakipjetuCiH9YF2fF0:16736:0:99999:7:::';

print "Input: $input\n";
my $enc = `openssl enc -base64 -A <<< $input`;
print "Encrypted Output: $enc\n";
my $dec = `openssl enc -base64 -A -d <<< $enc`;
print "Decrypted Output: $dec\n";
```

Output:

```
# ./temp.pl
Input: build:$6$n2cR7cY/$aKv6qQRWjYMIQIyAdTsw6nPtMzEZoqHziqyrL9sn/m29k5mkQjgcwZarA.8lAte6mmDGakipjetuCiH9YF2fF0:16736:0:99999:7:::
Encrypted Output: YnVpbGQ6Ly9tMjlrNW1rUWpnY3daYXJBLjhsQXRlNm1tREdha2lwamV0dUNpSDlZRjJmRjA6MTY3MzY6MDo5OTk5OTo3Ojo6Cg==
Decrypted Output: build://m29k5mkQjgcwZarA.8lAte6mmDGakipjetuCiH9YF2fF0:16736:0:99999:7:::
```

The issue I am facing is the decrypted string is not same as input string provided to encryption. I see all the characters after `$` are removed. May I know what `$` resembles here and how can I retain entire string back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to encode and decode Base 64 strings then you should use the [`MIME::Base64`](http://metacpan.org/module/MIME::Base64) module

The code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;

my $input = 'build:$6$n2cR7cY/$aKv6qQRWjYMIQIyAdTsw6nPtMzEZoqHziqyrL9sn/m29k5mkQjgcwZarA.8lAte6mmDGakipjetuCiH9YF2fF0:16736:0:99999:7:::';

print "Input: $input\n\n";

my $enc = encode_base64($input);
print "Encrypted Output: $enc\n";

my $dec = decode_base64($enc);
print "Decrypted Output: $dec\n";
```

### output

```
Input: build:$6$n2cR7cY/$aKv6qQRWjYMIQIyAdTsw6nPtMzEZoqHziqyrL9sn/m29k5mkQjgcwZarA.8lAte6mmDGakipjetuCiH9YF2fF0:16736:0:99999:7:::

Encrypted Output: YnVpbGQ6JDYkbjJjUjdjWS8kYUt2NnFRUldqWU1JUUl5QWRUc3c2blB0TXpFWm9xSHppcXlyTDlz
bi9tMjlrNW1rUWpnY3daYXJBLjhsQXRlNm1tREdha2lwamV0dUNpSDlZRjJmRjA6MTY3MzY6MDo5
OTk5OTo3Ojo6

Decrypted Output: build:$6$n2cR7cY/$aKv6qQRWjYMIQIyAdTsw6nPtMzEZoqHziqyrL9sn/m29k5mkQjgcwZarA.8lAte6mmDGakipjetuCiH9YF2fF0:16736:0:99999:7:::
```